# Cross Browser HTML5 File Uploader

Tags: javascript, php, html

Am trying to find any cross browser HTML5 file uploader , i searched a lot but didn't find any full working example , i tried **"uploadify"** but its flash and HTML5 version needs more that ie9 but i wont something to work on ie8 , my goal is to make an uploader that works on mobiles plus on ie8 , safari , Google chrome and Firefox.

am keeping as a last option to use any html5 uploader with uploadfiy and show the uploader depending on the browser type and version.

any recommendations ? or ideas can help me solve this issue .

Thanks,

Comment: "my goal is to make an uploader that works on mobiles plus on ie8 , safari , Google chrome and Firefox". I wouldn't think that you finding one on the internet to use would necessarily class that as you making it? Unless of course you intend to build from there code, but I can't imagine that would be allowed in most cases. Maybe consider building one from top to bottom yourself?

Comment: am still thinking from where to start , i think i should build two uploaders html , html5 and view them depending on the browser and device

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/). From the description:

> Allows you to upload files using HTML5, Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.